# Dockerfile to run python spark (pyspark code) as master/driver/worker as the same machine

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, pyspark

Looking for a dockerfile to containerize my python code which looks something like this

`main.py`

```
import os, datetime

from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, split, col, sum, lit
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.1" pyspark-shell'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("starting main function")
    # build spark session
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MainDemo").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    
    print(spark)
    print(type(spark))

    # Enable hadoop s3a settings
    # spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
    # spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    # spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3A")

    # read data from publc bucket into Spark DF
    data_path = "s3://humor-detection-pds/Humorous.csv" 
    df = spark.read.csv(data_path)

    # # apply spark transformations
    print(df.show())
    spark.stop()
```

Sample Dockerfile:

```
FROM bitnami/spark:3-debian-10
USER root
WORKDIR /opt/app
ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
# USER 185
#Copy python script for batch
COPY main.py /opt/app/main.py

CMD ["/bin/bash"] # Ran the container specifying the entrypoint and tried running the code.
```

I have looked at the following resources:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/spark-py
- https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-spark

**Update**:

Additional logs:

```
root@REDACTED_HOST:/opt/mlp# export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="REDACTED_TOKEN";
root@REDACTED_HOST:/opt/mlp# export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="REDACTED_KEY";
root@REDACTED_HOST:/opt/mlp# export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="REDACTED_ID";
root@REDACTED_HOST:/opt/mlp# cat <<EOF >>main.py
> import os, datetime
> from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame
> from pyspark.sql.types import *
> from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, split, col, sum, lit
> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>
> # os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.1" pyspark-shell'
>
>
>if __name__ == "__main__":
>     print("starting main function")
>     # build spark session
>     spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MainDemo").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
>
>     print(spark)
>     print(type(spark))
>
>     # Enable hadoop s3a settings
>     spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
>     spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
>     spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3A")
>
>     # read data from publc bucket into Spark DF
>     data_path = "s3a://humor-detection-pds/Humorous.csv"
>     df = spark.read.csv(data_path)
>
>     # # apply spark transformations
>     print(df.show()
> EOF
root@REDACTED_HOST:/opt/mlp# python main.py
starting main function
## Job is stuck here...
```

The job has stuck after this, though the file is very small 1.8MiB. The file is an open source file(s3).

```
 $ aws s3 ls s3://humor-detection-pds/Humorous.csv --summarize --human-readable                                                          [ruby-2.6.8p205]
2020-05-20 04:41:39    1.8 MiB Humorous.csv

Total Objects: 1
   Total Size: 1.8 MiB
```

But couldn't make it work with aws s3 dataset, any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get? Also, how are you providing your AWS keys and why did you comment the s3a setttings?

Comment: @OneCricketeer added additional logs and findings.

Comment: You need to run the code using `spark-submit`, not `python` command

Comment: I am able to run the above script(giving a local file) with python command.
Spark cannot run without spark-submit?

Comment: `spark-submit` will load the necessary Spark classpath options, including parsing of `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` (which you commented out, but still...). Regardless, the job is not really "stuck". Look at the container logs and open the SparkUI to see what the Spark executors are doing