# Simple PySpark script using Dockerfile not able to run

Tags: docker, pyspark, dockerfile

So I have a `test.py` file that creates a dataframe and outputs a csv:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])
df.write.csv("test", header=True)
```

I'm trying to get this to run via Docker but with zero luck.

I created the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM apache/spark-py:v3.3.0
COPY test.py test.py
# RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip && pip3 install pyspark==3.3.0
RUN apt-get update -y &&\
    apt-get install -y python3 &&\
    pip3 install pyspark==3.3.0
CMD ["python3", "test.py"]
```

and run the following to run the `test.py` script in Docker:

```bash
docker build -t ch_image --rm . && docker run --rm --name ch_container ch_image
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 31.23 kB
Step 1/4 : FROM apache/spark-py:v3.3.0
 ---> d186e5bd67b6
Step 2/4 : COPY test.py test.py
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 460491fa3ac9
Step 3/4 : RUN apt-get update -y &&    apt-get install -y python3 &&    pip3 install pyspark==3.3.0
 ---> Running in 21d6432b8d7b

Reading package lists...
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update -y &&    apt-get install -y python3 &&    pip3 install pyspark==3.3.0' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I've tried:

- `COPY test.py .`
- `CMD ["/opt/spark/bin/pyspark", "test.py"]`
- `RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip && pip3 install pyspark==3.3.0`

Any help to understand why I'm not able to run the script would be much appreciated.

Comment: see if this setup helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/73340248/2986344

Answer (score 1):

You got "permission denied" error. Could you please add "USER root" between step 2 and step 4 in your dockerfile as shown below?

```
FROM apache/spark-py:v3.3.0
COPY test.py test.py
USER root
RUN apt-get update -y &&\
    apt-get install -y python3 &&\
    pip3 install pyspark==3.3.0
CMD ["python3", "test.py"]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).